# Как исправить ошибку плагина, который определяет IP адрес?

Tags: php, wordpress, php8

Видимо при переходе на php8, получаю ошибку при установке очередного плагина:

`` Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` ``

Ругается на такой код, а именно на первую же строку:

```
function some_plugin_name_get_remote_address() {
    $remote_addr = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'):
            getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'):
            getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'):
            getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'):
            getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'):getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

    $remote_addr = str_replace('for=', '', $remote_addr);

    return $remote_addr;
}
```

Как правильно расставить скобки?
Сам не разберусь, с php не на «ты».
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Этот код написан неграмотным школьником. Исправлять его не надо, а надо удалить целиком, оставив только IP адрес клиента

```
function some_plugin_name_get_remote_address() {
    return getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
}
```

Есть такое понятие, "[карго культ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82) код". И вот эти скобочки как раз и являются наглядным примером такого культа. Не понимая ни что такое "IP адрес", ни смысла слова "настоящий", начинающие программисты городят такие вот из самолеты из соломы, думая, что призывают духов протокола TCP/IP, которые волшебным образом сообщат некий "всамделишный" адрес клиента.

Не понимая при этом, что получают результат, ровно противоположный ожидаемому. Если в REMOTE_ADDR не может содержаться ничего, кроме IP адреса, то во всех этих скобочках содержатся *HTTP заголовки*. А сейчас даже школьники уже знают, что любые НТТР заголовки элементарно подделываются. И написать туда можно что угодно. В чем уже [давно убедились авторы этого сайта](https://habr.com/ru/articles/158417/).

Поэтому всегда надо использовать только REMOTE_ADDR.

В редких случаях, когда веб-сервер стоит за криво настроенным прокси, приходится этот адрес брать из заголовков. Но даже в этом случае надо не перебирать все возможные заголовки скопом, а брать адрес из одного  конкретного: того, в который этот прокси пишет адрес клиента, и только в случае [если запрос пришел именно с этого прокси](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/b50f5e281d722cb0f4c296f908bacc3e2b721957/Request.php#L786).

Comment: Почему? Насколько я понимаю, код в вопросе пытается заголовки прокси вытащить в первую очередь, а потом уже адрес, если их не оказалось.

Comment: Этот код тоже выдаёт ошибку ```Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "some_plugin_create_folder" not found or invalid function name in...``` 

Может быть дело в php8 и его особенностях вроде дополнительных скобок? Я не раз уже сталкивался с подобным, но в разных вариантах «слегка старых» плагинов.

Comment: @Qwertiy вы вообще можете отличить заголовок TCP пакета от HTTP заголовка? Если нет, то у меня для вас плохие новости

Comment: @milcheloveck Вы вообще понимаете, что ошибок может быть больше, чем одна? И что эта, еще одна ошибка, к вашим скобочкам уже никакого отношения не имеет?

Comment: @Qwertiy и кстати, не стоило апать соседний ответ. Его автор, *как это здесь всегда бывает,* не понимает кода, который пишет. То есть это кривой код и сам по себе, безотносительно дурацкой идеи получения IP адреса из НТТР заголовков

Comment: @Ипатьев, насколько я понимаю, `REMOTE_ADDR` - это адрес, с которым установлено соединение, а всё остальное - http-заголовки, которые может выставить прокси-сервер, если он намеренно не хочет скрывать адрес клиента. А почему код кривой, я так и не услышал.

Comment: 1) Ответ не связан с вопросом 2) Ответ без каких либо объяснений и доказательств, просто поверьте и всё 3) Если глянуть в реализации популярных фреймворков (zend, symfony) то там именно перебор этих парамертов а не тупо REMOTE_ADDR. В ситуации где и они и ты не объясняют своих действий лучше поверить создателям фреймворков, чем фиг его знает кому

Comment: @Qwertiy при чем здесь "скрыть" адрес клиента? Что за детский сад? Прокси не скрывают адрес клиента. Они так работают. Скрывает адрес сам клиент, если хочет его скрыть, а на сервере проверка делается таким тупым способом. Чтобы понять, почему код кривой, надо таки немножечко знать РНР. Если уж беретесь выступать под этим тегом со своим авторитетным мнением.

Comment: @ТёмаKornishon не надо, пожалуйста, путать реальность со своими не очень актуальными  представлениями о ней :) Если вы не являетесь специалистом в какой-либо области, то надо очень тщательно проверять свои заявления. Впрочем, даже если являетесь - тоже. Такого фреймворка как "zend", уже давно не существует в природе, и упоминать его нет смысла. А в symfony этого неграмотного мусора, разумеется, нет. Существует он только в нубских поделиях, потому что всем хочется обладать неким Тайным знанием. "REMOTE_ADDR для лохов, а крутые пацаны используют непонятные, но солидно выглядящие скобочки".

Comment: @Ипатьев, ты так и не ответил на мой вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy что именно вам неясно? Как найти онлайн шелл для РНР или как скопировать и запустить в нем приведенный ниже код? :)

Comment: @Ипатьев, и нафига мне его запускать?

Comment: @Qwertiy чтобы ответить себе на вопрос "а почему код кривой?" :)

Comment: @Ипатьев, а при чём тут запуск?

Comment: @Qwertiy это несложный способ ответить себе на свой вопрос :) Подход, так сказать, который мы тут отечески прививаем приходящим нубам :)

Comment: @Ипатьев, в общем, ты придумал какую-то ерунду, которую пытаешься доказать вообще не имея аргументов. Понятно.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, конечно :)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать вот так

```
$remote_addr = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP') || getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') || ...;
```

при || операторах смотрятся с первого и дальше пока не встретится true, следовательно пропустит все не найденные свойства (т.к. getenv вернет false) и остановится если найдет

Точно также работают и операторы && но в таком случае остановка если встретится false

Comment: Я был некорректен, указав лишь часть функции. Прошу прощения. Можете ли указать — как сделать правильно в данном коде? 

```function some_plugin_get_remote_address() {
 $remote_addr = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'):
   getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'):
   getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'):
   getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'):
   getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'):getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

 $remote_addr = str_replace('for=', '', $remote_addr);

 return $remote_addr;
}```

Comment: function some_plugin_get_remote_address() { $remote_addr = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP') || getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') || getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED') || getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR') || getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED') || getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'); $remote_addr = str_replace('for=', '', $remote_addr); return $remote_addr; }

Comment: Эх... Всё-таки не получается: 

```Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "some_plugin_create_folder" not found or invalid function name in 
site.com\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:310 Stack trace: #0 
site.com\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #1 
site.com\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() #2 
site.com\wp-admin\plugins.php(194): do_action() #3 {main} thrown in 
site.com\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 310
```
Не в скобках ли дело?

Comment: файл с функцией some_plugin_get_remote_address не подключен до вызова хука